# Response.Redirect and Tempdata

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore

I want to use `Response.Redirect()` inside the controller to redirect to a certain page or item in Sitecore and use the `TempData` value set in the controller in that view.

Currently value is getting set inside the controller, but not able to use it in the View.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that Tempdata is not useful in Sitecore due to how Sitecore takes over the request and response pipelines.

I recommend you use Session instead.  The Session variable will be available to you after you set it in one Controller and redirect to another page.  Just make sure to clear the Session variable after you use it.